# Can I filter an Android app by the mobile network operator?

Tags: android, networking, filter, operator-keyword, carrier

For example, I want to make a specific app so that it only shows up and can be downloaded by users on the Vodafone network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. While selecting the country filter you get an option to choose the network operator in the playstore console.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do it.Goto

```
Google Play Developer Console  > Aplication > Pricing and Distribution .
```

You can select service providers for specific countries.

You app will be visible to selected service providers and specific countries.

Comment: Thanks. If you have multiple APKs under the same application listing, can you filter each APK by carrier?